# How can i tell Visual Studio 2019 NOT to recompile all source files if the timestamp of a header has changed?

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild

At work, i'm working on a large Visual Studio c++ project with several thousands source files, which take 2 hours + to build. To pull third party libraries in, we use scripts and conan, which tend to copy over  header files, even when they didn't change. Any time this happens Visual Studio starts to rebuild everything from scratch, which is quite annoying.
In linux, it's usually sufficient to touch all object (.o) files and let make/cmake/whatever directly go to the linker stage, which may take some few minutes.
How could i do this in Visual Studio? When i touch all .obj files it will still recompile everything. It seems like the build state is stored elsewhere, and the time stamps on the .obj files are disregarded. How can i override Visual Studio's up-to-date check, and let it (for instance) just execute the link.exe?

In the build directory, i start up a cygwin shell and execute find . -name '*.obj' | xargs touch. The object files now have a newer timestamp than all the source and header files. I was expecting Visual Studio would just try to link the object files to produce the build targets, instead it still starts to compile everything.

Comment: From the MSBuild log you should be able to get the actual link command. My guess is there are more files passed to the linker than just the *.obj files. It also seems to be a serious problem that a C/C++ package manager doesn't handle header files very well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is not i wouldn't know how to invoke the linker, but how to continue working with msbuild 'normally', that is, just building the solution but without recompiling everything. Probably precompiled header files are part of the problem, because the .pch files get rebuilt each time after updating the source directory, followed by compiling each and every source file.

Comment: You want to see the link command to see what files are being used by the command and therefore what dependencies you need to touch. Yes, if the package headers in question are included in the pre-compiled headers and you are not touching the .pch then the .pch will be rebuilt and all the source using the .pch will be rebuilt.